# Python Installation throwing lots of MemoryError()'s

Tags: python, linux, centos, cpanel

I just installed (and re-installed) python 2.7.3 on my centos 6.3 server with cpanel built into it to the /opt/python2.7.3 directory on my system.  I also installed it with the --enable-shared flag and then configured setuptools for it.  I am having issues now though when I am trying to easy_install or use basic python thigns such as bin/pcreate (i  am building a web application) with it throwing MemoryError()'s

Im confident that there is memory available as free -m shows there is over 2gb of memory available on the system.  Here is an example of one of the MemoryError traceback's:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


  File "bin/pcreate", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pyramid==1.4a3', 'console_scripts', 'pcreate')()
  File "/home/urcellar/betaurcellar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 318, in load_entry_point
  File "/home/urcellar/betaurcellar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2221, in load_entry_point
  File "/home/urcellar/betaurcellar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
  File "/home/urcellar/betaurcellar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.4a3-py2.7.egg/pyramid/scripts/pcreate.py", line 5, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 90, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext
MemoryError
```

Im not really sure what is broken or what to do...i did a clean install so it's definitely not the python download or installation, has to be something else on the system....

Thanks

EDIT: ulimit-a

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 1000000
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 127196
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 4096
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 14335
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: Your code is barely getting started; it's loading standard libraries. I would *not* expect to see memory errors unless something else is *severely* restricting the available memory to Python.

Comment: any ideas on what that could be?

Comment: No, sorry, no idea, but it'll probably be external to Python.

Comment: updated post with `ulimit -a`

Comment: 32- or 64-bit OS? If the latter, 32- or 64-bit Python? (Likely not relevant, but I once had a problem building 32-bit 2.6 on 64-bit linux, where it ended up expecting to have >4GB of memory even though it only had 4GB of process space…)

Comment: Did you find the answer? I've got the same problem, random MemoryError exceptions in library code. I've also got Python 2.7.3 running Ubuntu under VirtualBox.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply, the solution ended up being Cpanel had a fork shell bomb protection built in and it was limiting the size of python's memory.  Should check that out.